# Trying to send window.width via PHP (Blank page on POST)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to figure out a way to save and then echo or print_r the window.innerwidth and window.innerheight..

I did it like below and I keep getting a blank page

first page

```
<html>

<body>


<form action='trythis2.php' method='POST'>
<input type='hidden' id='dimensions' name='dimensions'>

<input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#dimensions").html($(window).width());
}).resize();

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Second page

```
<?php


$thisis = $_POST['dimensions'];

print_r($thisis);


?>
```

and on the POSTED page its just blank no text or anything. I wanted it to show my browsers width.

Comment: Erm, your aren't posting anything. Look in to AJAX.

Comment: well how do I make the value of the inner.width into a variable so I can send it over to the next page. I do not want to just reload it on the same page with AJAX.

Comment: @Kevin1990M you are using `html()` which is wrong. Check my answer.

Comment: Deleted my answer. It's 4:30 AM here. My brain has officially switched off and either you don't understand the code or I don't understand what you want. I'll tackle this tomorrow *hopefully* if it is still unresolved.

Comment: unless i'm in a galaxy, far far away, you cannot run php in my browser. (to get the size)

Comment: Must be in a galaxy far away. Cause it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `val()` to set or retrieve the value of input field. `html()` is used to set inner html of html elements. Hope this will help.

Svae this code as .php extension

**Code:**

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['dimensions'])){

    $thisis = $_POST['dimensions'];

    echo $thisis;

    exit();

    }

    ?>

    <html>
    <head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' id='dimensions' name='dimensions'>

    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $("#dimensions").val($(window).width());

    $(window).resize(function() {
        $("#dimensions").val($(window).width());
    });

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hey man, tried it and it gives me a blank page as well. I put that script in. Submitted to my next page called trythis2.php then I said $test = $_POST['dimensions]; then I said echo $test; and it was just blank.

Comment: I changed my first page to exactly what you have.